# How does this CSS code to center an element work?

Tags: css

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

This is CSS code for centering a button in the viewport. Can somebody explain how this works? I found it somewhere online and it seems to work but I don't get the need for margin-right and transform. Naturally the code doesn't work without them but intuitively I feel the first three should be enough to center the element. I'm relatively new to CSS so I'd understand if this is considered a silly question :)

Comment: I don't think you need `margin-right`. Obviously the `transform` is necessary, because otherwise the left and top sides of the centered element will be at the 50% mark, and it will extend rightward and downward from there.

Comment: this article explains it, including an example with `margin-right` https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this article: https://css-tricks.com/quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/. Simply using the first three lines of css (position, top, and left) will center the top left corner of the object, which will make the whole object completely off-center. The negative translation moves the object up and to the right by half of its height and width, respectively, which makes the object centered. In fact, I don't think you even need the margin-right code, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Flex box is also really good for this. On the container. dispay:flex; justify-contents: center; align-items: center; - will center contents of the flex container horizontally and vertically.